# Where to install MediaInfo CLI in Windows?

Tags: command-line-interface, mediainfo

I don't feel very confident about permissions and security in Windows.

I have just dowloaded and unzipped the .zip that contains MediaInfo CLI (not the full installer). It works flawlessly from the download folder (pointing the terminal to that location), but it does not seems to be a good place, isn't it?

So, should I drag the whole folder to the Applications folder, or to the Documents folder?

Is there a proper location for a CLI like MediaInfo and use it just writing "MediaInfo.exe" in the terminal?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Like every other program, you must put it in the path environment variable so that it works from anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few portable apps as well and I store them in a folder called **Tools** located in the root of my **User Profile**:

```
%UserProfile%\Tools
```

Some portable programs work as a single **exe** file while others have additional files they depend on to run - such as **CrystalDiskMark** - so I tend to place the folder with all its contents in my **Tools** folder.

```
%UserProfile%\Tools\CrystalDiskMark
```

Next you'll want to add the appropriate **User** *environment variables*:

Click **Start**, begin typing "*environment...*" and select **edit the system environment variables** once you see it appear > click **Environment Variables** button.

1. Under **User variables for** , select **Path** > **Edit**
2. Click **New** and add each path that is relevant for all of your
   portable programs
3. Click **OK** to accept the changes

*You can leave the **System Properties** window open for now...*

`<username>` is obviously *your* username. It's best to Copy/Paste each path needed...

As an example, here are all the ones I have for my **Tools**:

```
C:\Users\<username>\Tools
C:\Users\<username>\Tools\CrystalDiskInfo
C:\Users\<username>\Tools\ffmpeg\bin
C:\Users\<username>\Tools\HandBrake
C:\Users\<username>\Tools\MediaInfo
C:\Users\<username>\Tools\mkvtoolnix
```

I've only got two tools in the root of **Tools** at this time: **exiftool.exe** and **imagex.exe**

These portable programs will now be available from the **Command Prompt** regardless of the starting path.

**One additional step (optional):**
You can add your **Tools** folder as a **System variable** so you can access it for other reasons using **%tools%**.

Under **System variables**, click **New**

- **Variable name:** `tools`
- **Variable value:** `C:\Users\<username>\Tools`
- Click **OK**

Now test out your new **%tools%** variable and run each program to ensure they work. If not, double check you added the full path to each executable.